Update string items in a List only when the current string size is equals to 2 in c#
I have two lists, one of them is a list of 2 character strings (dteSubstringList).
The other list is a variable string length list (table).
I only want to update the items in the second list when the number of characters equals 2.
I was able to do this using while, but I want to use a more elegant way, like LINQ.
This is the current code:
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Count; i++)
        {
            if (table[i].Data.Length == 2)
            {
                table[i].Data = dteSubstringList[index].Mte;

                index++;
            }
        }


Would be great to provide sample data. Elegant way, LINQ?! Nah, I don't see LINQ approach can improve in terms of performance, readability in your case.

LINQ does not really work that well for updating lists. It is more about projecting and filtering data. Your current solution is readable enough, and if it works as intended there is little reason to spend time and effort chasing what would at best be a very minor improvement. The time is better spent at something else, like writing unit tests.

"want to update the items in the second list " How are the items in list1 linked to the items in list2?

The first list contains the best character pair combinations for an English text. The second list is recalculated based on the translation of the English text, replacing it with better matches. Typically ROMs for games from old consoles like the NES use a type of compression called DTE (Dual Tile Encoding). I'm making a program to facilitate these translations, accessing the memory areas of both the text and the DTE table.

Linq is not that good in data modification (we usually use Linq to query); I suggest List.ForEach instead:
int index = 0;

table.ForEach(item => {
  if (item.Data.Length == 2)
    item.Data = dteSubstringList[index++].Mte;
});


Hmm what if one where to insert a .Where(t => t.Data.Length == 2) between the table and ForEach? Would you say thats overkill? But its nice to meet a fellor List.ForEach enjoyer

@SMSTJ: Please, note that ForEach is List<T> method, so we can't use .Where(...) which turns List into enumeration. Willy-nilly we want to put item.Data.Length == 2, let's do it in ForEach and work with original list instead of creating and disposing an enumerator.

Ah you are right forgot that a .ToList() part would also need to have been included. Thx for drawing my attention to that

@SMSTJ: Exactly: we have unwanted overhead with Linq (creating list copy - .ToList(), creating enumerator for small collections).

Although... lets say that the table list contains a massive amout of entires. Would the Where be effective then, due to it being able to eliminate many antries that it doesnt need to concern itself with?

@SMSTJ: No, Where checks the condition (as we do) and then it doesn't eliminate items, it skips items: we have the very same original table list. Moreover, Where brings (small) overhead: it creates enumerator and when looping we use a bit more complex loop.

hmmm I see. Well thank you for your patience ^^

Well I personally think that what you have is quite sufficient, but I will still try to give you an answer. The only part where I would say a readability improvement can be made is like this
var tabDateWithTwo = table.Where(t => t.Data.Length == 2).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < tabDateWithTwo.Count; i++)
{
     tabDateWithTwo[i].Data = dteSubstringList[i].Mte;
}

Edit: if you want a more Linqy approach you can combine my Where Filter with Dmitry Bychenko s List.ForEach. I would do it in this Post but that would feel like shameless stealing of his answer.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I mean... will it though? The indexes are only increased when they get an entrie with a length of 2 in the OP post. Same with mine.

@TimSchmelter well yes. I simply get all objects that fit the criteria and only loop through them, instead of looping through all and checking for each step. The order and indexes should stay the same

@TimSchmelter, this was my first thought also; however, the index of the second table is incremented separately with index++;. Therefore, the update is not performed on corresponding original indexes but on the indexes of the filtered table.

@TimSchmelter ? I think you are confusing something here. In the OPs case 12 would also get the "1". i and index are seperate in the OPs post

@TimSchmelter Well no. The index in the OPs code comes from simple incrementing of their index variable. The increment happens after every found Length == 2. the full length of table does NOT affect the index. index only depends on the amount of entries with a length of 2

Also @TimSchmelter dont forget that theese arent simple string lists, but Lists that contain objects. So mapping intregrety should be maintained since the filteredList I create contains the SAME objects

@TimSchmelter could be. But for the sake of my answer I ran on the assumption that their code is fully operational, and they just want to "make it more linqy"

@TimSchmelter KK got it. Have a pleasant day ^^
